# Inequalities on determinants of rational matrices.

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, determinant

Here are two claims in a proof I'm reading that I don't get. Can I have some more elaboration?

> Let $A=\left(\dfrac{p_{i j}}{q_{i j}}\right)_{i j}, i,j=1,...,n$, and
> $\operatorname{det}(A)=\dfrac{p}{q}$ for completely reduced fractions.
> $\dfrac{p_{i j}}{q_{i j}}, \dfrac{p}{q}$ and $q_{i j}, q>0 .$ We have:
>
> - $ q+1 \leq \prod_{i, j=1}^{n}\left(q_{i j}+1\right)$.
> - By the definition of the determinant via the Laplace formula: $|\operatorname{det}(A)| \leq \prod_{i, j=1}^{n}\left(\left|p_{ij}\right|+1\right)$.

Comment: The denominator of the determinant is going to be some factor of its components since it is a completely reduced fraction: $kq = \prod_{i,j=1}^n q_{ij}, k > 0$, and the inequality follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\prod_{i,j=1}^n q_{ij}$ is a common multiple of all the denominators in the determinant formula. This implies that there is some $m \in \mathbb{N^+}$ such that:

$$ mq = \prod_{i,j=1}^n q_{ij} $$

Because each $q_{ij}, q, m > 0$, the following inequality follows:

$$ q + 1\leq \prod_{i,j=1}^n \big(q_{ij} + 1\big) $$

For the second part, we can use induction on $n$:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{n+i} \frac{p_{ni}}{q_{ni}} |C_{ni}| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(|p_{ni}| \prod_{j,k=1, j \neq n, k \neq i}^{n} \big(|p_{jk}| + 1\big)\Big) \leq \prod_{i=1,j=1}^n \big(|p_{ij}| + 1\big) $$

where $C_{ij}$ is the minor matrix in the Laplace formula.

Note that in the last step, we use the fact that $|p_{ij}| + 1 \geq 1 $ in order to simplify the expression:

$$  \prod_{j,k=1, j \neq n, k \neq i}^{n-1} \big(|p_{jk}| + 1\big) \leq \prod_{j,k=1, j \neq n}^{n-1} \big(|p_{jk}| + 1\big) $$

and then:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(|p_{ni}| \prod_{j,k=1, j \neq n}^{n} \big(|p_{jk}| + 1\big)\Big) = \Big(\sum_{i=0}^n |p_{ni}|\Big)\prod_{j,k=1, j \neq n}^{n} \big(|p_{jk}| + 1\big)$$

We can further simplify this using the fact:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n |p_{ni}| \leq \prod_{i=1}^n \big(1 + |p_{ni}|\big) $$

There's probably an easier way but this stood out to me since Laplace expansion is inductive by nature.

**Edit:**

Probably easier approach to the second part is just realising what the expansion of $ \prod(1 + |p_{ij}|)$ is and that the terms in $|\det(A)|$ ignoring all $q_{ij}$ form some subset of the terms in that expansion

Comment: Is it possible to have $|\operatorname{det}(A)| \leq \left( \prod_{i, j=1}^{n}\left(\left|p_{ij}\right|+1\right) \right) -1$?

Comment: Yes, I think so, seeing it's true for $1\times1$ matrices and we could use $\sum_{i=1}^n |p_{ni}| \leq \Big(\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + |p_{ni}|)\Big) - 1$